NestJS versioning on sub-paths
I want to create a NestJS api that has paths like /service-one/v1/* and /service-two/v1/* where the URI versioning should be after the service name.
The versions from /service-one and /service-two should be independent of each other.
The @Version() annotation provided by NestJS is pretty much what I need, but it appears to only work for the root of the path (e.g., /v1/service-one).
Is there a way to create a custom annotation, similar to @Version(), but with the version defined at the second part of the path?
I came up with the following, which is working okay for v1 but not v2 (I figured NestJS is removing duplicate paths, so only the first one will be registered):
// src/main.ts
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    await app.listen(3003);
}

bootstrap();

"consumer":
// src/consumer/consumer.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConsumerController } from './consumer.controller';
import { TasksModule } from './tasks/tasks.module';

@Module({
  controllers: [ConsumerController],
  imports: [TasksModule]
})
export class ConsumerModule {}

// src/consumer/consumer.controller.ts
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('consumer')
export class ConsumerController {
}

"tasks":
// src/consumer/tasks/tasks.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksController } from './tasks.controller';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [TasksController],
  providers: [TasksService],
  exports: [TasksService],
})
export class TasksModule {}

// src/consumer/tasks/tasks.controller.ts
import { Controller, Get, Post, Version } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiVersion } from "../../ApiVersion";

@Controller("consumer/tasks")
export class TasksController {
    @Post()
    @ApiVersion("v1")
    createV1() {
        return 'This action returns all tasks for V1';
    }

    @Post()
    @ApiVersion("v2")
    createV2() {
        return 'This action returns all tasks for V2';
    }
}

@ApiVersion() handling:
Create annotation:
// src/ApiVersion.ts
import { SetMetadata } from "@nestjs/common";

export const API_VERSION_KEY = "apiVersion";
export const ApiVersion = (version: string) => SetMetadata(API_VERSION_KEY, version);

Middleware to get version from URI:
// src/versioning.middleware.ts
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from "@nestjs/common";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

@Injectable()
export class VersioningMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const pathParts = req.path.split("/");
        const versionPart = pathParts[2];
        const version = versionPart && versionPart.startsWith("v") ? versionPart : "v1";

        /** Attach the version to the request object */
        req['apiVersion'] = version;

        /** Remove version part from the URL so that it matches the route paths defined in controllers */
        req.url = req.url.replace(`/${version}`, '');

        next();
    }
}

// src/version.guard.ts
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Reflector } from "@nestjs/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { API_VERSION_KEY } from "./ApiVersion";

@Injectable()
export class VersionGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
    }

    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const handler = context.getHandler();
        const version = request['apiVersion'];

        const requiredVersion = this.reflector.get<string>(API_VERSION_KEY, handler);
        if (!requiredVersion) {
            return true;
        }
        return version === requiredVersion;
    }
}

Use middleware and guard:
// src/app.module.ts
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConsumerModule } from "./consumer/consumer.module";
import { VersioningMiddleware } from "./versioning.middleware";
import { APP_GUARD } from "@nestjs/core";
import { VersionGuard } from "./version.guard";

@Module({
    imports: [ConsumerModule],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [
        AppService,
        {
            provide: APP_GUARD,
            useClass: VersionGuard
        }
    ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {

    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
            .apply(VersioningMiddleware)
            .forRoutes({ path: "*", method: RequestMethod.ALL });
    }
}

